# Remove extra edges in face with hole?

Tags: faces, edges

I need to get rid of these (blue) edges. They belong to grey faces I want to merge in one ring-like. Mint colored square is a hole in grey face.

[image: Face with extra edges]

I might have missed the same question, so if the solution exists already, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: you can't create a hole without 2 edges connecting the inner edges with the outer edges